# How I can convert this SQL query to Elasticsearch query in Visual studio?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch query, so I'm lost on how to convert this SQL query to an Elasticsearch query in visual studio:

```
WHERE   
(x IS NOT NULL) AND (y IS NOT NULL) OR
(x IS NOT NULL) AND (z IS NOT NULL) OR
(x IS NOT NULL) AND (q IS NOT NULL)
```

I know the Elasticsearch query should be something like this with "Should" and "Must", but I'm sure it's far from the correct syntax and visual studio gives me too many red lines with this query which says "The name Must/Exist/Field doesn't exist in the current context".

```
             .Query(q => q
                    .Bool(m => m
                            .Should( s => s
                            .Must(
                         b => b.Exists(t => t.Field(y => y.x)),
                         b => b.Exists(t => t.Field(y => y.y))),

                            .Must(
                         b => b.Exists(t => t.Field(y => y.x)),
                         b => b.Exists(t => t.Field(y => y.z))),

                            .Must(

                         b => b.Exists(t => t.Field(y => y.x)),
                         b => b.Exists(t => t.Field(y => y.q))))
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me with finding the best way to convert this where with SQL query to Elasticsearch. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that it worked for me and I liked to share with others.

```
     .Query(q => q
         .Bool(m => m
            .Must(
                b => b.Exists(t => t.Field(y => y.x)),
                b => b.Bool(t => t
                   .Should(
                       b => b.Term(t => t.y, false),
                       b => b.Term(t => t.z, false),
                       b => b.Term(t => t.q, false))))
```